# Decimal in javascript

Tags: javascript

The text box should accept onli decimal values in javascript. Not any other special characters. It should not accept "." more than once. For ex. it should not accept 6.....12
Can anybody help???

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
function IsDecimal(str)
{
    mystring = str;
    if (mystring.match(/^\d+\.\d{2}$/ ) ) {
        alert("match");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("not a match");
    }
}
```

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/3/81089/numaric-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.test method:

```
if (/\d+(\.\d{1,2})/.test(myTextboxValue)) //OK...
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Mask plug in is the way to go!
http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/#mm_demos

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you do not want anything but an integer or a decimal to be typed into the field, you'll need to look at the value
as each key is pressed. To catch pasted input, check it again onchange.

```
textbox.onkeyup=textbox.onchange=function(e){
    e= window.event? event.srcElement: e.target;
    var v= e.value;
    while(v && parseFloat(v)!= v) v= v.slice(0, -1);
    e.value= v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you want to validate a form input before sending it to the server. Here is some example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Form Validation</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function validate(){
            var field = document.getElementById("number");
            if(field.value.match(/^\d+(\.\d*)?$/)){
               return true;
            } else {
               alert("Not a number! : "+field.value);
               return false;
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validate();">
         <input type="text" id="number" width="15" /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="send" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just whipped this up. Useful?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validNum(theField) {
  val = theField.value;
  var flt = parseFloat(val);
  document.getElementById(theField.name+'Error').innerHTML=(val == "" || Number(val)==flt)?"":val + ' is not a valid (decimal) number';
}
window.onload=function(){
  validNum(document.getElementById('num'));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="num" id="num"
onkeyup="return validNum(this)" /> <span id="numError"></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```